# Processing: how to load a 3d Blender model?

Tags: 3d, processing, blender

How can I load a 3-d Blender model into the Processing environment?

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to find a plugin specifically for Processing, but since Processing can do OpenGL, you can just use any model loader for Java that can render to OpenGL.

The OBJ file format is probably most convenient; Blender can export to OBJ. [Here](http://www.pixelnerve.com/processing/libraries/objimport/) is an OBJ loader that can be used with Processing. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/joglobj/) is a JOGL renderer based on that loader.